# Statistics about gaps in DNA sequences

Tags: python, performance, numpy, bioinformatics, numba

Noobie to Numba here, I'm trying to get faster code from existing function but the result is not faster. 10 times faster would be heaven, but I know nothing about optimization.
This is code about parsing gaps in DNA sequences pairwise alignment and doing statistics about it.
The code looks like this:

```
import re
import time
import numpy as np
from numba import autojit, int32, complex64
sstart = 10
send = 52
absoluteRoiStart = 19 #rank of the first nucleotide in the ROI
absoluteRoiStop = 27 #rank of the the first nucleotide after the ROI
#ROI is here  'TATCGA---CAG|TA-----TACTA-C|G--TTGAGAGAGAC-CCCA'
#between |    'T--CGACCAC--|-GATCGAG---ATC|GGCTT--------CTC--A'
source =      'TATCGA---CAGTA-----TACTA-CG--TTGAGAGAGAC-CCCA'
sequence =    'T--CGACCAC---GATCGAG---ATCGGCTT--------CTC--A'
realSource = 'AAGGTTCCAATATCGACAGTATACTACGTTGAGAGAGACCCCACATGACTGACTACGT'

tresholds = {
    "DEL" : {
        "other" : 2,
        "slippage": 2,
        "quantity" : 7
    },
    "INS" : {
         "other" : 3,
         "slippage": 3,
         "quantity" : 7
    },
    "MUT" : {
        "other" : 3,
        "slippage": 3,
        "quantity" : 7
    },
    "NA" : {
        "other" : 3,
        "slippage": 3,
        "quantity" : 7
    }
}

def getAllGaps(sequence1, sequence2):
    starts = []
    stops = []
    lengths = []
    types = []
    locations = []
    gap = '(\-)+'
    x = re.compile(gap)
    for m in x.finditer(sequence1):
        #Get Gap satrt, stop and length
        start,stop = m.span()
        #Test if Gap is slippage(compression or extension)
        if start > 1 and stop < len(sequence2):
            h = sequence2[start-1:stop+1].upper()
            i = sequence1[start-1:stop+1]
            repetitions = i.replace('-', h[0]).upper(), i.replace('-', h[-1]).upper()
            if h == repetitions[0] or h == repetitions[1]:
                slippage = True
            else:
                slippage = False
        else:
            slippage = False
        starts.append(start)
        stops.append(stop)
        lengths.append(stop-start)
        if slippage:
            types.append(2)
        else:
            types.append(1)
        locations += range(start, stop)
    d = [starts, stops, lengths, types]
    return {'locations': locations, 'bounds': d}

def getAlignmentData(source, sequence, sstart, tresholds):
    insertionData = getAllGaps(source, sequence)
    alignmentLength = len(source)
    oneArray = np.ones(alignmentLength)
    oneArray[insertionData['locations']] = 0
    absoluteIndex = oneArray.cumsum()-1+sstart
    relativeIndex = np.arange(alignmentLength)
    tf = (absoluteIndex >= absoluteRoiStart) & (absoluteIndex < absoluteRoiStop)
    absoluteBounds = absoluteIndex[tf]
    relativeBounds = relativeIndex[tf]
    relativeRoiStart = int(relativeBounds.min())
    relativeRoiStop = int(relativeBounds.max())
    events = np.array(insertionData['bounds'], dtype=np.int32)
    insertionStartingInRoi = events[:,(events[0] >= relativeRoiStart) & (events[1] <= relativeRoiStop)]
    print(insertionStartingInRoi)
    deletionData = getAllGaps(sequence, source)
    events = np.array(deletionData['bounds'], dtype=np.int32)
    deletionOverlappingRoiOrStartingInRoi = events[:,((events[0] <= relativeRoiStart) & (events[1] >= relativeRoiStart)) | ((events[0] >= relativeRoiStart) & (events[1] <= relativeRoiStop))]
    print(deletionOverlappingRoiOrStartingInRoi)

t0 = time.time()    
getAlignmentData(source, sequence, sstart, tresholds)
t1 = time.time()
getAlignmentData(source, sequence, sstart, tresholds)
t2 = time.time()

print(str(t1-t0)+' to first try')     
print(str(t2-t1)+' to second try')
```

When I add the `@jit` decorator on the two functions, I get slower code. Do I need to do something special, like signatures? Can Numba make this code faster or do I need to use Cython?

Comment: Numba has two modes - "object mode" and "nopython mode", and only nopython mode is faster (although it can often change object mode loops to nopython mode). Neither dictionaries, lists or strings are supported in nopython mode (see http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.18.1/reference/pysupported.html) so it's going to struggle. You could probably make some progress by converting your strings to a numpy array numeric representation before calling the functions.

Comment: (Note that large chunks of numpy are supported by nopython mode, it's just discussed on a different manual page http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.18.1/reference/numpysupported.html)

Comment: Ok, I didn't know about nopython mode. I also noticed that someone has similar problems with a cumsum numpy function I also use, here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25950943/why-is-numba-faster-than-numpy-here

Comment: Maybe you're right, I won't jit the first function dealing with strings and convert everything to arrays in the second function, thanks.

Comment: Will it work with a function that returns many arrays? How can I add the signature for such a function?

Comment: have you tried pypy?

Comment: No, not yet, I'm still stuck with numpy and numba... I'll let you know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After profiling your code as:

```
import cProfile, pstats, StringIO
pr = cProfile.Profile()
pr.enable()
for it in range(0,10000): 
    getAlignmentData(source, sequence, sstart, tresholds)

pr.disable()
s = StringIO.StringIO()
sortby = 'cumulative'
ps = pstats.Stats(pr, stream=s).sort_stats(sortby)
ps.print_stats()
print s.getvalue()
```

You will get:

> ```
> 1370129 function calls (1370122 primitive calls) in 3.249 seconds
>
>    Ordered by: cumulative time
>
> ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
> 10000    1.003    0.000    3.249    0.000 test.py:71(getAlignmentData)
> 20000    1.071    0.000    1.684    0.000 test.py:38(getAllGaps)
> 20000    0.171    0.000    0.171    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.array}
> 20000    0.160    0.000    0.160    0.000 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
> 10000    0.018    0.000    0.121    0.000 {method 'min' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
> 400022    0.119    0.000    0.119    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
> 180000    0.107    0.000    0.107    0.000 {method 'replace' of 'str' objects}
> 100000    0.106    0.000    0.106    0.000 {range}
> ```

You can use Cython or f2py to optimise memory management starting with `getAllGaps`, which is simpler, and then go for `getAlignmentData`.

Keep in mind that you need to deactivate outputs and take long runs to measure real speedup.

If you compile your code using `nuitka` you can get 9x speedup.

> ```
>      110128 function calls (110121 primitive calls) in 0.355 seconds
>
> Ordered by: cumulative time
>
> ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
> 20000    0.158    0.000    0.158    0.000 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
> 10000    0.011    0.000    0.101    0.000 /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:28(_amin)
> 10000    0.022    0.000    0.096    0.000 /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py:141(ones)
> 20000    0.025    0.000    0.081    0.000 /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py:192(compile)
> 10000    0.008    0.000    0.076    0.000 /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:25(_amax)
> 20000    0.056    0.000    0.056    0.000 /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py:230(_compile)
> 10000    0.037    0.000    0.037    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.copyto}
> 10000    0.037    0.000    0.037    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.empty}
> ```

All you need to do is install [nuitka](http://nuitka.net) and run:

```
$ nuitka mycode.py
```

You also need a larger dataset to run a proper benchmark. Since it's easy to keep small data in cache, the profiler can provide misleading results.